# how to use RE2 library when match arguments are unknown

Tags: c++, re2

I am not able to use RE2::FullMatchN when the number of match arguments are determined at run time.

```
const RE2::Arg* args[10];
int n;
bool match = RE2::FullMatchN("abcd@abcd.com", "([^ @]+)@([^ @]+)", args, n);
```

At the end, I want to obtain 2 strings in above example - abcd and abcd.com

Comment: Have the user provide the string, the regex *and* the number of capture groups?

Comment: yes he provides all the three parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `RE2` as an object. If `RE2` object has successfully parsed regex you can call `NumberOfCapturingGroups()` method. Knowing how many capturing groups there are you can dynamically allocate an array of pointers to `RE2::Arg`.

Here an example function:

*I also suggest you to wrap regex in '(' - ')' since `re2` does not return by default `0th` argument for full match as many other APIs do.*

```
bool re2_full_match(const std::string & pattern, const std::string & str, std::vector<std::string> & results)
{
    std::string wrapped_pattern = "(" + pattern + ")";
    RE2::Options opt;
    opt.set_log_errors(false);
    opt.set_case_sensitive(false);
    opt.set_utf8(false);
    RE2 re2(wrapped_pattern, opt);
    if (!re2.ok()) {
        /// Failed to compile regular expression.
        return false;
    }

    /// Argument vector.
    std::vector<RE2::Arg> arguments;
    /// Vercor of pointers to arguments.
    std::vector<RE2::Arg *> arguments_ptrs;

    /// Get number of arguments.
    std::size_t args_count = re2.NumberOfCapturingGroups();

    /// Adjust vectors sizes.
    arguments.resize(args_count);
    arguments_ptrs.resize(args_count);
    results.resize(args_count);
    /// Capture pointers to stack objects and result object in vector..
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < args_count; ++i) {
        /// Bind argument to string from vector.
        arguments[i] = &results[i];
        /// Save pointer to argument.
        arguments_ptrs[i] = &arguments[i];
    }

    return RE2::FullMatchN(StringPiece(str), re2, arguments_ptrs.data(), args_count);
}
```

---

But in the spirit of regex I suggest you to use `^....$` instead of `full_match`, and rename `full_match` to `find`:

```
bool re2_find(const std::string & pattern, const std::string & str, std::vector<std::string> & results)
{
    std::string wrapped_pattern = "(" + pattern + ")";
    RE2::Options opt;
    opt.set_log_errors(false);
    opt.set_case_sensitive(false);
    opt.set_utf8(false);
    RE2 re2(wrapped_pattern, opt);
    if (!re2.ok()) {
        /// Failed to compile regular expression.
        return false;
    }

    /// Argument vector.
    std::vector<RE2::Arg> arguments;
    /// Vercor of pointers to arguments.
    std::vector<RE2::Arg *> arguments_ptrs;

    /// Get number of arguments.
    std::size_t args_count = re2.NumberOfCapturingGroups();

    /// Adjust vectors sizes.
    arguments.resize(args_count);
    arguments_ptrs.resize(args_count);
    results.resize(args_count);
    /// Capture pointers to stack objects and result object in vector..
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < args_count; ++i) {
        /// Bind argument to string from vector.
        arguments[i] = &results[i];
        /// Save pointer to argument.
        arguments_ptrs[i] = &arguments[i];
    }

    StringPiece piece(str);
    return RE2::FindAndConsumeN(&piece, re2, arguments_ptrs.data(), args_count);
}
```